How do I pipe the video stream of a Raspberry Pi Camera Module to the HDMI port or composite video output
I am using a Raspberry Pi 5. I want to send the camera stream directly to one of the HDMI ports or to the composite video output (preferable). My goal is to display only the camera stream on the output, not the entire desktop.
I am not interested in using web-based streaming solutions.
How can I achieve this?

There's no composite video on an RPi5

@Dougie There are two contacts near the HDMI port where a wire or a pin header can be soldered. They can be used for composite video.
